# Windows CMD Customization Quest¡on

Tags: windows, terminal, cmd, command, command-prompt

If the possible is following, could someone help me do it?

I want to customize the Windows 7 command prompt (cmd.exe) so that instead of it showing C:\Users\Blah> , it shows

[HH:MM] text@text ~ $

Essentially, I want to make it look like it's Arch Linux but it's not.

/halp

Comment: Use the `prompt` command.  Type `help prompt` for syntax

Answer (score 0):

As foxidrive says in comment, the built in help documentation for PROMPT describes the available meta characters for the PROMPT command.

There is no direct way to get time as HH:MM. You will have to use backspaces to strip off the minutes and seconds. Also, hours less than 10 may have a leading space instead of a leading zero, depending on regional settings.

```
prompt [$T$H$H$H$H$H$H] text@text ~ $$
```

Comment: The regional settings allow the user to change the `%time%` format so it could be set to `HH:MM` and then use `%time%` in the prompt.

Comment: @foxidrive - True, the regional setting should be reflected in the `$T` output, so I updated my answer a bit. But I don't think it is possible to get a dynamic time value in the prompt using `%time%` or `!time!` - you must use `$T`.

Comment: This partly helped, I have most of it working, but I still need a way to have a way to have the path without C drive showing. for e.g: `[Blah] text@text Users/Username/Desktop ~ $`
so there is no C:\, and the \'s have turned into /'s.

If there is no way to do this in just CMD, could I somehow do this with a batch file?

Comment: @HudsonSerge - I'm pretty sure you are limited to the dynamic values listed in the help, plus any string literals. There is no way to dynamically manipulate the prompt via batch or any other scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink) which supports customizing the prompt with Lua scripts, as well as adding Bash-style line editing, completion, and history just like Arch Linux.